Pgfplot tikz 3d curve on surface plot
I would like to create a plot similar to this one using tikz pgfplots:

I was checking the documentation, but could not find anything similar.
The surface plot is generated by f(x,y) = x + y.
The curve is given by the intersection of g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 with f.
I am only interested in the 3d plot, the projection into the x-y-plane is not necessary.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=0.8
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            legend pos=outer north east,
            domain=-2:2,
            xlabel={$x_1$},
                ylabel={$x_2$},
                zlabel={$f(x_1, x_2) = x_1 + x_2$}
        ]
            \addplot3[
                surf,
                colormap/hot2,
                samples=41
            ] {x + y};

            \addplot3+[mark=none,thick]({x},{y},{x*x+y*y});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

I think that a simpler approach would be to calculate a parametric formula for the intersection by hand or by using a CAS. Then you could plot it manually with the plain tikz command, plot.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
zmin=-3, zmax=3,
]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=faceted interp,
domain=-1.5:1.5, samples=21
]{x+y};
\addplot3[
domain=0:340, samples=18, smooth cycle,
samples y=1,
variable=\t,
]({sqrt(0.5)*cos(\t)+0.5},{sqrt(0.5)*sin(\t)+0.5},{sqrt(0.5)*cos(\t)+0.5+sqrt(0.5)*sin(\t)+0.5});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thanks a lot, that was what I was looking for. :-)
